# How to ignore _vti_cnf and _vti_pvt folders in the nominated folder and all sub-folders of nominated folder?

Tags: tortoisegit

I have this in my **.gitignore** file located in the root of my repository:

```
# Expression Web tracking files
/Help/_vti_cnf
/Help/_vti_pvt
```

But it turns out I need to ignore these two folders in any *sub folder* of **Help** or below. See:

[image: Not Versioned]

How do I modify it to do that?

Comment: Is the file named `gitignore` or `.gitignore` and where is this file located?

Comment: @MrTux Updated question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no path which starts with `/Help/_vti_cnf`, thus no files are ignored. Change to `/Help/PublisherDatabase/_vti_cnf`, `/Help/*/_vti_cnf` (all direct subfolders contining `_vti_cnf`), `/Help/**/_vti_cnf` (all subfolders containing `_vti_cnf`) or `_vti_cnf` (ignore `_vti_cnf` everywhere).

For more information see https://git-scm.com/docs/gitignore

Comment: I needed the `**` approach. Thanks.

Comment: There was another thing I had to do! I had to delete the existing files that were already in the repository from it. :)